# Tool for Analyze the class diagram of big C++ framework

Tags: c++

Can you please tell me which is the best tool that generate the pictorial representation of the C++ source code.
I have big C++ framework code and i want to understand that code so i need some tool that generate some graphs, class diagram or some pictorial representation of all class to understand the code. Can you please tell me tool or any other way to understand the big  C++ framework code ?

Comment: Member for a `1 yr 3 months`, Asked `15 Questions`, Accepted `0` answers, Votes Cast `0`. Why should people help you, If you don't even acknowledge their efforts in helping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen is free, popular, and easy to use.
http://www.doxygen.nl/

Grab the graphviz plugin to generate some fancy graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not free, but in a past company I used *Enterprise Architect* to generate a very useful class diagram of a very big code-base.

Comment: i have download Enterprise Architec .. it looks good but in that first i have to create *.EAP file but how to create that file ?

Comment: Sorry, can't remember, it's a good couple of years ago. I only remember selecting the c++ source directory somewhere, which caused EA to import/generate a really massive class diagrams, with relationships between classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse CDT for this. It has [Type Hierarchy View](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/reading-code/type-hierarchy/) among other tools to navigate/analyse source code. It can build type hierarchies for user defined types on the fly on big C++ project.

Answer (score -1):

If you used GCC, you might consider making a GCC plugin or a GCC [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension. But that will take you some time.

Perhaps some expensive commercial tools like Coverity could help.